# How is the min_rank used with the flights database

Tags: r

I'm exploring the `https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#add-new-variables-with-mutate` r for data science handbook and don't really understand the min_rank() operator.  Doing the exercises it asks to Find the 10 most delayed flights using a ranking function. How do you want to handle ties? Carefully read the documentation for min_rank().

here is the code that I performed that doesn't work. Please explain:

```
min_rank(flights, dep_delay)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the results of min_rank in to a new column, e.g.:

```
f2 <- flights %>% 
  mutate(rank = min_rank(dep_delay))
```

Where showing just the selected rows:

```
f2 %>% 
  select(dep_delay, rank)
```

You get this:

```
# A tibble: 336,776 x 2
   dep_delay   rank
       <dbl>  <int>
 1         2 208140
 2         4 219823
 3         2 208140
 4        -1 164763
 5        -6  48888
 6        -4  94410
 7        -5  69589
 8        -3 119029
 9        -3 119029
10        -2 143247
# ... with 336,766 more rows
```

Here is another example where you can see all the rows.

```
aa <- tibble(y = c(9, 8, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6),
             x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5))

aa %>% 
  mutate(rank = min_rank(y))
```

Which gives us:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
      y     x  rank
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     9     1     7
2     8     2     6
3     3     3     1
4     4     4     2
5     5     4     3
6     7     4     5
7     6     5     4
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
mutated = mutate(flights, total_delay = dep_delay + arr_delay)
arrange(mutated, desc(total_delay))
```

basically by doing this you create a new colum with the total delay in minutes with which you sort your data by total delay time using arange